# Why do some applications started using bash "bind -x" hang the terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal, vim, tty, console

I have these bindings in .bashrc:

```
bind -x '"\C-f":"vim -c MRU"'
bind -x '"\C-g":"lazygit"'
```

and after starting vim using Ctrl-F and exiting it, it leaves the terminal in a state where it doesn't echo typed commands until i run `reset`. Similarly, if I start lazygit using Ctrl-G, it always hangs after I open an editor from it using 'e'.

Are these applications not restoring the terminal mode upon exit, or is due to something bash is doing before or after running the application ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the applications are not cleaning up for some reason. This behavior could be countered by wrapping these commands in a `sh -c "<command>; reset"`